# How to use binary executables in cron tab on web hosting

Tags: c++, cron, hosting, web

I use a web hosting (leadhoster.com) for my website and I use cron tab to run my PHP script on regular basis. But I need my script work much faster, as it processes images, so I want to write it in C++.

But how is it possible to create binary executable on a web hosting? I did not find CC or gcc compiler on the hosting. Should I install same version of Linux on my home computer and build my code there to prepare binary executable? How this kind of things is usually done?

Comment: Please don't migrate this to SF. It's as off topic there as it is here.

Answer (score 0):

- They won't appreciate it, if it's even possible. Most shared hosting providers disable all this access, since it's a major security risk.
- You could install the same linux they're using and compile it there. You will probably need to build a fat statically linked binary, since you probably can't install libraries either.

Answer (score 0):

The only people who can help you with this as leadhoster's support group. They will most likely tell you that you can't do it on a shared server.

Comment: thanks! well, that's what they told: they don't allow this. I wonder what people do if they need to process data: PHP is ages slower than C++. Is it the same situation with Java that it is also not allowed on shared hosting?

Comment: @Andrey Rubliov: I guess people just switch to a VPS. Then you can do anything, just at a slighly higher cost. Shared hosting is cheap only because the features are limited. There are some shared hosting providers who allow more (like http://dreamhost.com/web-hosting/ -- disclaimer: I use their service), but they are few and usually more expensive.